# Individually editing ARTIST pages in Big Cartel

Tags: bigcartel

Help! I'm using Big Cartel as a home for my record label, and for the most part I can bend it to fit my needs. However, a huge problem I'm having is with the artist page. Rather than being an aggregate of products for sale by that artist, I need the relevant artist page to contain a bio and information, yet I can't find any way to actually edit these pages. They seem to exist in some existential web limbo. Does anyone know how to edit the artist pages manually?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a built in 'page' for each individual artist, instead the code for these lies in the **Products** page.

You can make changes by heading to *Customize Design > Advanced > Products* in your admin, and clicking *Customize* to enable code editing. From there you'll need to insert some **if / elsif** statements to display different content per artist, like so:

```
{% if page.name == 'Artist 1' %}
  Artist 1 Content Here
{% elsif page.name == 'Artist 2' %}
  Artist 2 content here
{% elsif page.name == 'Artist 3' %}
  Artist 3 content here
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Nick, thank you! Is there a specific place in the products page I need to insert this code into? I'm not having any luck getting it to work out.

Comment: You'll need to place the code wherever you want the bio/information to go on the page - this varies depending on what theme you're using.

You'll also need to replace 'Artist 1' etc with the exact artist names that show up on the page, and that you're putting it on the ProductS page (not individual Product page) as well.

Comment: So this isn't technically editing the artist's page, it's just putting a blurb about the artist on the product page? Sorry, I'm a bit lost.